# VS2012 Express Application does not work on Windows XP after changing Prerequisites

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

I've been here before looking for a solution and some that I have seen do not seem to work.

My situation is that I have built an MIS Application on VS2012 VB.Net and it works perfectly on Windows 7, but some users still use Windows XP and I cannot reinstall for all of them as it would be inconvenient for me and my team.

All I want is the system to be compatible on the XP OS. I changed the prerequisites from Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (bla bla bla) to Microsoft .NET Framework 4. I have even published a few times with trying to have the Windows Installer 4.5 prerequisite unchecked and by also trying to publish with Windows Installer 3.1 checked instead. Ive tried with VS2010 as well and still nothing. The following are error logs i got:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 5.1.2600.196608 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.1
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)
```

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///E:/XP%20Edition/CHBAH_JACSystem.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of E:\XP Edition\CHBAH_JACSystem.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from file:///E:/XP%20Edition/CHBAH_JACSystem.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + Manifest XML signature is not valid.
        + SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [4/11/2017 3:33:09 PM] : Activation of E:\XP Edition\CHBAH_JACSystem.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [4/11/2017 3:33:10 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from file:///E:/XP%20Edition/CHBAH_JACSystem.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SignatureValidation)
        - Manifest XML signature is not valid.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
        - SignatureDescription could not be created for the signature algorithm supplied.
        - Source: System.Security
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignedInfo(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
            at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignature(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
            at System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml.CheckSignatureReturningKey(AsymmetricAlgorithm& signingKey)
            at System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.SignedCmiManifest.Verify(CmiManifestVerifyFlags verifyFlags)
            at System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.ValidateSignature(Stream s)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Comment: You say you changed the _prerequisites_ from .NET 4.5 to .NET 4, but did you actually recompile the application in .NET 4.0? It's the application's target framework that matters to whether it will work or not.

Comment: How do I recompile the application in .Net 4.0? @VisualVincent

Comment: I came across a similar issue a few days ago, and this link was helpful: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f5b934d2-e8b9-4401-b038-b84aefbdf836/clickonce-exception-reading-manifest?forum=winformssetup

Comment: You've got to change the target framework, then build your project again: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Well, I did a rebuild but still no luck. Im testing on a Windows XP virtual machine and the terms I see the most in the error logs are regarding the Manifest file, that it could not be opened or it is invalid, or the Manifest XML Signature is not valid, or the Security Cryptography, or the Signature description cannot be created...